# const unsigned char* conversion to/from string or const char*

Tags: android, c++, pointers, casting, malloc

I am lost in the underworld of pointers!  Here is my problem,

It is very quirky and I can only control one of the functions so please don't say I need to redesign.
This is being compiled in Linux Ubuntu 11.04 using android-ndkr7.  It is a purely native application (or service) that will run on an android phone.  I am using google test to verify my class/functions.
The first function (my test class) has to declare the unsigned char*, it passes it to the 2nd function to be used as output (crypt::encryptBuffer), encrypt takes the declared variable, allocates memory for it and passes it to a third function which is where the value is being placed into it as output.

Crypt.h

```
class Crypt
{
public:

   Crypt();
   ~Crypt();

   bool encryptBuffer(const unsigned char* inDecryptBuffer, const int inputSize, unsigned char** outEncryptBuffer, int*  pOutSize);

};

#endif
```

Crypt.cpp

```
#include "Crypt.h"
#include "pan/crypt.h"

static unsigned char HydraEncryptionKey[] = {0x17, 0x43, 0x9B, 0x55, 0x07, 0xAE, 0x73, 0xB1, 0x32, 0x10, 0xE0, 0x22, 0xD9, 0xC7, 0xF2, 0x3B};

bool AccCrypt::encryptBuffer(const unsigned char* inDecryptBuffer, const int inputSize, unsigned char** outEncryptBuffer, int*  pOutSize)
{
    int encryptedSize;
    pan::aes128_cbc enc(HydraEncryptionKey);

    // see how long the encrypted data will be and allocate space for the data
    encryptedSize = enc.output_len( inputSize );

    *outEncryptBuffer = (unsigned char*)malloc(encryptedSize + 4);

    enc.encrypt(inDecryptBuffer, *outEncryptBuffer, inputSize );
    return true;
}
```

CryptTest.cpp

```
#incude "Crypt.h"
#include <gtest/gtest.h>

#define CHECK_COND(X, a, b, c) { \
if(X) \
{ \
    printf("FAIL: %s\n", c); \
    printf("Press any key to continue");\
    getc(stdin);\
}\
else \
{ \
    printf("PASS: %s\n", c); \
}\
}

#define EXPECT_EQ(a,b,c)  CHECK_COND((a != b), a, b, c)

const char* decBuff = "something";
const int inputSize = 10;
unsigned char* encBuffTest = NULL;
int pOutsize = 0;

class cryptTester : public testing::Test
{
    protected:
    virtual void SetUp()
    {
        cryptTest = new Crypt();
        cryptTest->encryptBuffer((const unsigned char*)decBuff, inputSize, &encBuffTest, &pOutsize);
    }

    virtual void TearDown()
    {
    }

    Crypt* cryptTest;

};
TEST_F(AccCryptTest, decryptBuffer)
{
    int poutSize = 0;
    EXPECT_EQ(true, accCryptTest->decryptBuffer((const unsigned char*)encBuffTest, pOutsize, &outDecryptBuffTest, &poutSize), "decryptBuffer(valid, valid)");

}
```

This will compile fine, however when I run it on the phone I get a segmentation fault.  I cannot figure out where this is happening as I have not been able to setup debugging correctly from the adb shell.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You should be able to debug this in the comfort of a fully supported development environment (such as running native code on in gdb or your favorite other debugger, on your desktop rather than phone). Once you find the issue there, it should not have differences when compiled under the NDK for Android. Whatever is failing has nothing to do with unsigned char vs. char.

Comment: This is obvious, but I suggest testing for the pointers after you allocate memory (malloc) and create object (new).

Comment: -1 not the real code. `cryptTest = new Crypt();` where `cryptTest` is a class name should not compile. wasted people's time.

Comment: Cheers and hth. - Alf,  you are correct, this is not my real code.  I had to quickly change the names of things as I cannot put the real code on here due to legal reasons.  I also had to strip a lot of things out. However, if you read the comments before and after the code, you will see that Crypt is the name of the class and cryptTest is the name of the instantiation being used in the google test functions. It is declared outside of the virtual void setup(). So yes, it will compile.   Don't be a hater.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code seems ok, maybe the error is in the `encrypt` method:

```
enc.encrypt(inDecryptBuffer, *outEncryptBuffer, inputSize );
```